# Overload Magento Report Collection on config.xml

Tags: xml, magento, overriding, overloading, extends

I'm trying to create override of the class `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection`, I made my custom class and configured it on `etc/config.xml` but for some reason its not working..

It's not my first override class and I think I know more or less how things are working there but maybe its a edge case of extending report collection (?)

What exactly should I write on the `config.xml`?

My code is:

```
<models>
....
  <reports>
      <rewrite>
        <resource_quote_collection>Mage_Customization_Model_Reports_Resource_Quote_Collection</resource_quote_collection>
      </rewrite>
  </reports>
.....
</models>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
<reports_resource>
    <rewrite>
        <quote_collection>Mage_Customization_Model_Reports_Resource_Quote_Collection</quote_collection>
    </rewrite>
</reports_resource>
```

And something a bit off topic. Don't use `Mage` as your namespace. Be more creative and leave that to the core developers.

Comment: Thanks but its doesnt work.. about the namespace i know but im maintaining existing and non-mine code.. so i have no choice ;)

Where path should i use for the class `Mage_Customization_Model_Reports_Resource_Quote_Collection`?

Comment: This is strange. It should work. Make sure you cleared the cache.

Comment: Cleared.. what path its should be in?

Comment: What do you mean what path? I don't understand. Is this what you mean? `Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection')` ?

Comment: path of the new class file on filesystem, right now is located under `/app/code/local/Mage/Customization/Model/Reports/Resource/Quote/Collection.php`